# CSS place div center in the centered div

Tags: html, css

What I have done is to place a `div` in the center. However, I cannot make those buttons to be placed in the center of the centered `div`. I want to place all rows to be at the center. Those separators can be adjusted, as I just want to separate them.

[image]

```css
    .button {
        padding: 13px 5%;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        color:black;
        background-color: #f4ef73;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        float: left;
    }    

    .row {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }

     #center {
         background-color:blue;
         margin: auto;
         width: 400px;
         height: 200px;
     }   

     .separatorRow{
         width:100%;
         height:20px;
         float:left;
     }

     .separatorCol{
         width:5%;
         height:60px;
         float:left;
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">1</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">2</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">3</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">4</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="separatorRow"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">1</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">2</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">3</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">4</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```css
 .button {
        padding: 13px 5%;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        color:black;
        background-color: #f4ef73;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        float: left;
    }    

    .row {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }

     #center {
         background-color:blue;
         margin: auto;
         width: 400px;
         height: 200px;
     }   

     .separatorRow{
         width:100%;
         height:20px;
         float:left;
     }

     .separatorCol{
         width:5%;
         height:60px;
         float:left;
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">1</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">2</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">3</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">4</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="separatorRow"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">1</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">2</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">3</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
            <div class="button">4</div>
            <div class="separatorCol"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.button {
  padding: 13px 5%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f4ef73;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#center {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.separatorRow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.separatorCol {
  width: 5%;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">2</div>
      <div class="button">3</div>
      <div class="button">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="separatorRow"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">2</div>
      <div class="button">3</div>
      <div class="button">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But it is not dynamic, I mean when the screen size decreases, those buttons are still in the same position. Is there any way to fix it? As I don't want to allow scrolling

Comment: replace `width:400px;` in for id `#center` to `max-width:400px;`.If not getting let me know

Comment: But can the space between buttons be larger?

Comment: @androidnewbie So better to use `display:flex` property to `row` class name.  If you want eqal space all use `justify-content:space-between`

Comment: I mean the effect of using `separatorCol`, so that I can just add some spaces between buttons

Comment: Can set `margin` for buttons

Answer (score 2):

FlexBox can help you like below :)

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.button {
        padding: 13px 5%;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        color:black;
        background-color: #f4ef73;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }    

    .row {
        width:100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding:20px;
    }

     #center {
         background-color:blue;
         margin: auto;
         width: 400px;
         height: 200px;
     }   

     .separatorRow{
         width:100%;
         height:20px;
    

     }

     .separatorCol{
         width:5%;
         height:60px;
   
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="center">
        <div class="row">
   
            <div class="button">1</div>
    
            <div class="button">2</div>

            <div class="button">3</div>
 
            <div class="button">4</div>
   
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="button">1</div>
 
            <div class="button">2</div>

            <div class="button">3</div>

            <div class="button">4</div>
      
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But it is not dynamic, I mean when the screen size decreases, those buttons are still in the same position. Is there any way to fix it? As I don't want to allow scrolling

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  padding: 13px 5%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f4ef73;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

#center {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">2</div>
      <div class="button">3</div>
      <div class="button">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">2</div>
      <div class="button">3</div>
      <div class="button">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: But it is not dynamic, I mean when the screen size decreases, those buttons are still in the same position. Is there any way to fix it? As I don't want to allow scrolling

Answer (score 1):

You can set it using `display: inline-block` check updated snippet below;

```css
.button {
  padding: 13px 5%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f4ef73;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 2.5% 20px 2.5%;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#center {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.separatorRow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.separatorCol {
  width: 5%;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">2</div>
      <div class="button">3</div>
      <div class="button">4</div>
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">2</div>
      <div class="button">3</div>
      <div class="button">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But it is not dynamic, I mean when the screen size decreases, those buttons are still in the same position. Is there any way to fix it? As I don't want to allow scrolling.

Comment: you can write mediaquery for this. when you use `inline-block` in small screen bydefault it wrap.

Comment: It would be appreciated, if you could give more details.

Comment: if you use `inline-block` then there is no need to use any separator.  In small screen it automatically wrap to another line. also you can manage it's alignment using text-align in parent tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button {
        padding: 13px 5%;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        color:black;
        background-color: #f4ef73;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        float: left;
        margin: 5%;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        width: 18.75%;

    }    

    .row {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }

     #center {
         background-color:blue;
         margin:  auto;
         width: 400px;
         height: 200px;
     }   

     .separatorRow{
         width:100%;
         height:20px;
         float:left;
     }
```

Use border-box to include border width within size specified. 
Instead of using `.seperaterow` include margin values button class.

I have used width of 18.75% because in your code you mentioned width to be 5%,so 25% for space (5*5), remaining 75% for 4 buttons (75%/4).

```
margin-right: 0px
margin-bottom: 0px
```

Because here we are using cumulative margin.Learn about cumulative and collapsing margin.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below may be it will useful

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I think since you are styling the `div` itself, this will create quite a mess